# Creating an executable jar file

Tags: java

I have extracted an executable jar file containing xml,java class etc. Actually this executable jar file is a library with dependencies. i need to modify a single line of code in one of the class files in this library. I have successfully edited the class file, now i want to repack it to executable jar. how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Just zip the whole thing back, a jar is just a zip file.

1. Unzip the .jar
2. Modify the class
3. Rezip the whole structure into a .zip
4. Rename it to .jar
5. There you go.

You can automate it with the [ant `<jar>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task for example.

As said by comments below you can use the `jar` tool that comes with the JDK installation.
`jar -xvf your.jar` to extract and `jar -cvf your.jar inputfiles`.
See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).

What makes the JAR executable is that it contains in its structure a file located in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` that describe what is the entry point class, like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: foo.bar.FooBar
```

Comment: Why use zip and not the jar tool?

Comment: Because any OS comes with zip/unzip this is pretty standard. And because it seems much simpler to explain it this way to OP, ignoring the fact that he does not really know how a jar works.

Answer (score 2):

using jar command you can do this

take a command prompt and got your root folder where all the classes. and use
following command

```
 jar -cvf myjarname.jar *

* means all the files and folders in that location
```

Comment: Simple and the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, verify that you have the file association for executable jars.  If you don't you can create this association with this batch file:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: this script creates a file association for executable .jar files
ECHO Creating .jar file association...
ECHO JAVA_HOME is %JAVA_HOME%
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_HOME GOTO :FAIL
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Executable Jar File" /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open" /ve /f
ECHO REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*" /f
REG ADD "HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%**" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\jarfile" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "Executable Jar File" /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open" /ve /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\jarfile\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "\"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe\" -jar \"%%1\" %%*" /f
ECHO Finished creating .jar file association for executable .jar files.
PAUSE
GOTO EOF
:FAIL
ECHO Script failed. JAVA_HOME not defined.
PAUSE
```