# (JAVA) Use Command Prompt to create .jar file from multiple .class files

Tags: java, command-line, jar, javac

I have written a .java file, called Main.java, and have compiled it using the javac in the Windows Command Prompt. The compiler is creating multiple .class files (called Main.class, Main$1.class, & Main$2.class--presumably because I have anonymous inner classes in my Main.java file). I am trying to create a runnable .jar file so I can double click a shortcut to run this application (it is a Java Swing application), but I am unsuccessful when I navigate to the directory of the three class files and type:

```
jar cfv file.jar Main.class Main$1.class Main$2.class
```

The Command Prompt then outputs this text:

```
added manifest
adding: Main.class(in 4871) (out = 2848)(deflated 41%)
adding: Main$1.class(in 1409) (out = 833)(deflated 40%)
adding: Main$2.class(in 1239) (out = 767)(deflated 38%)
```

Despite this, when I double click on the file.jar file in Windows Explorer, simply put, nothing happens. No swing application opens.

Hopefully someone can help me out with this. Thank you

Best...SL

Comment: Look at this question which answered your question. There has been plenty of question on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081920/creating-an-executable-jar-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the entry-point switch `-e` (with the name of the class containing the `main()` method) as such:

```
jar cfve file.jar Main Main.class Main$1.class Main$2.class
```

Comment: Thank you iamnotmaynard, this worked. I will accept this as the correct response once this website allows me to...

Comment: if java program have more dependence jar files. how to represent the lib path in command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

Something's gotta tell the java which class should be started automatically.
That's the Manifest - see description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)
You have to package the Manifest.mf in your jar.

Comment: In your case: add `Main-Class: Main` to a file Manifest.txt and `jar cfv file.jar Manifest.txt Main.class Main$1.class Main$2.class`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Command Prompt
2. cd go to the path where jar file exist
3. run command `jar xf fileName.jar`
4. It will generate com, `META-INF` & `Copyright.mk` files
5. Go to the particular package where u want to modify the class file (Basically   class files present in com directory)
6. Download the `JAD.exe` from google (Its Zip File)
7. Extract the Zip file you will get `jad.exe`
8. Place the class file (which u want to modify) in the folder, that contains `jad.exe`
9. Go to command prompt, run `jad fileName.clas`s (the class filename which u want to modify)
10. `fileName.jad` file will get generate , rename it as `fileName.java`
11. compile the `fileName.java` (if its referring to some other class file configure it in eclipse accordingly)
12. once compiled replace the class file in the directory defined in step 4
13. Go to command prompt, cd Step 4 path, run `jar cf fileName.jar` (* represents all the class files irrespective of directories)

Answer (score 0):

1. open cmd (windows+r type cmd)
2. simipily type command as a "jar" without quatoes
3. it will give some options and those usage.
4. use what you want
5. to create a jar file with class you to mention jar cfv filename.jar example.class 
   example2.class etc..
6. IF your using swing compile it with javac -deprecation SwingApplication.java but JDK version must be greater than version JDK1.1
7. run java SwingApplication
8. ALL THE BEst